# Appending a protected Object with an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I have a class that I am using as part of the CMB2 framework for WordPress. It has a protected object that I am trying to append a list of years to. My code looks like this in my function

```
function cmb2_team_members_metaboxes() {
    global $redux_rg;
    $prefix = '_cmb2_';
    $cmb_team_members = new_cmb2_box(array(
        'id'            => 'team_member_metabox',
        'title'         => __( 'Team Member Metabox', 'rev-group' ),
        'object_types'  => array( 'post_type_teammember', ), // Post type
        'context'      => 'normal', //  'normal', 'advanced', or 'side'
        'priority'     => 'high',  //  'high', 'core', 'default' or 'low'
        'show_names'   => true, // Show field names on the left
    ));
```

I add more fields then below I am trying to append the `years()` output to an options list of an HTML select / dropdown. to do this I need to append `$cmb_team_members->meta_box['fields']['_cmb_start_year']['options']` with the output array from the function `years()`. Below is where I am trying to extend `CMB2` class which is protected with the `years()` output.

```
class yearsClass extends CMB2
{       
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$cmb_team_members->meta_box['fields']['_cmb_start_year']['options'] = years();
    }
}
```

I know I am doing this completely wrong but I can't seem to crack this. Any help would be appreciated.

I have years defined in my functions.php file and it outputs:

```
array(
    2015 => 2015,
    2014 => 2014
)
```

When I output the CMB2 Object I get this:

```
CMB2 Object (
[cmb_id:protected] => team_member_metabox
[meta_box:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => team_member_metabox
        [title] => Team Member Metabox
        [type] => 
        [object_types] => Array
            (
                [0] => post_type_teammember
            )

        [context] => normal
        [priority] => high
        [show_names] => 1
        [show_on_cb] => 
        [show_on] => Array
            (
            )

        [cmb_styles] => 1
        [enqueue_js] => 1
        [fields] => Array
            (
                [_cmb2_division] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Division
                        [desc] => The division of the company this person works in (These can be edited in the Revolution Group theme options)
                        [id] => _cmb2_division
                        [type] => select
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_cmb2_photo] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Photo
                        [desc] => 
                        [id] => _cmb2_photo
                        [type] => file
                    )

                [_cmb2_position] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Position
                        [desc] => Job position
                        [id] => _cmb2_position
                        [type] => text
                    )

                [_cmb2_email] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Email
                        [desc] => Email address
                        [id] => _cmb2_email
                        [type] => text_email
                    )

                [_cmb2_bio] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Bio
                        [desc] => 
                        [id] => _cmb2_bio
                        [type] => wysiwyg
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                                [media_buttons] => 1
                                [textarea_rows] => 5
                            )

                    )

                [_cmb2_start_year] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Year Started
                        [desc] => The year the team member started with Revolution Group
                        [id] => _cmb2_start_year
                        [type] => select
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [_cmb2_certifications_repeat_group] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => _cmb2_certifications_repeat_group
                        [type] => group
                        [description] => Certifications (These can be edited in the Revolution Group theme options)
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                                [group_title] => Certification {#}
                                [add_button] => Add Another Certification
                                [remove_button] => Remove Certification
                                [sortable] => 1
                            )

                        [fields] => Array
                            (
                                [certification] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Certification
                                        [description] => Please select
                                        [id] => _cmb2_certification
                                        [type] => select
                                        [options] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [certification_year] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Year Obtained
                                        [description] => The year this certification was aquired
                                        [id] => _cmb2_certification_year
                                        [type] => select
                                        [options] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [_cmb2_skills_repeat_group] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => _cmb2_skills_repeat_group
                        [type] => group
                        [description] => Skills (These can be edited in the Revolution Group theme options)
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                                [group_title] => Skill {#}
                                [add_button] => Add Another Skill
                                [remove_button] => Remove Skill
                                [sortable] => 1
                            )

                        [fields] => Array
                            (
                                [skill] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Skill
                                        [description] => Please select
                                        [id] => _cmb2_skill
                                        [type] => select
                                        [options] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [_cmb2_fun_fact] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Fun Fact
                        [desc] => 
                        [id] => _cmb2_fun_fact
                        [type] => wysiwyg
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                                [media_buttons] => 1
                                [textarea_rows] => 5
                            )

                    )

                [_cmb2_order] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Order
                        [desc] => Order that the team member should be displayed. The lower the number the hghter on the list when displayed
                        [id] => _cmb2_order
                        [type] => text
                    )

            )

        [hookup] => 1
        [save_fields] => 1
        [closed] => 
        [new_user_section] => add-new-user
    )

[object_id:protected] => 0
[object_type:protected] => post
[mb_object_type:protected] => post
[updated:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[mb_defaults:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 
        [title] => 
        [type] => 
        [object_types] => Array
            (
            )

        [context] => normal
        [priority] => high
        [show_names] => 1
        [show_on_cb] => 
        [show_on] => Array
            (
            )

        [cmb_styles] => 1
        [enqueue_js] => 1
        [fields] => Array
            (
            )

        [hookup] => 1
        [save_fields] => 1
        [closed] => 
        [new_user_section] => add-new-user
    )

[fields:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[hidden_fields:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[data_to_save] => Array
    (
    )

[generated_nonce:protected] =>
```

)

Comment: You have a few things wrong here. `$this->$cmb_team_members`, you probably mean: `$this->cmb_team_members`. Also, you're calling a function `years()`, where is that defined? Lastly, in the base class `CMB2`, I don't see the `cmb_team_members` variable: https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/blob/master/includes/CMB2.php

Comment: I have years defined in my functions.php file and it outputs: Array
(
    [2015] => 2015
    [2014] => 2014
)

Comment: I have also edited my original question to add more details of whats defined and more context. @ian thanks for your answer. I will try a combo of what you mentioned and possibly my edit to the question to add more context may help you point me in the right direction. This is so far over my head. I know how to append a real array but these magic things are throwing me for a loop.